# Custom update in CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

is that possible to returns updated entity by custom update method instead of numbers of affected rows? How can I achieve this?

I would like to have sth like this:

```
 public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {

 @Modifying
 @Query(value="UPDATE data SET max_version = max_version + 1 WHERE id = 'A'", nativeQuery=true)
 Data updateDataByType();
}
```

instead of this

```
 public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {

 @Modifying
 @Query(value="UPDATE data SET max_version = max_version + 1 WHERE id = 'A'", nativeQuery=true)
 Integer updateDataByType();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the `@Modifying` annotation. because these methods can only be void and int. Otherwise you will get the error **`Modifying queries can only use void or int / Integer as return type`**.

But can be you can implement custom repository Implementation and return your updated entity after done with the query execution.

Reference: [Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)